# Android Studio with Facebook (Login+Share Function)

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, share

I am a beginner who making an android app by using android studio which need Facebook login+share function.

To add a Share button add the following code snippet to your view:

```
ShareButton shareButton = (ShareButton)findViewById(R.id.fb_share_button);
shareButton.setShareContent(content);
```

I don't understand my view is in which class? Where actually should i put the code?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO:SE. The site will not provide links to tutorials, it works another way: You search what you need online, you try, and if you have trouble with the code, then you report the problem here so that users can help you find the solution. See [ask].

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a layout for your class, in which you define an ID for `View`s. A button is an example of a such `View`. [This](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html) page about creating layouts should help you on that part, and explain what `findViewById()` does. That site is a great resource for beginning Android developers, so look around while you're at it.

For all Facebook interactions, Facebook has created an SDK you can add to your app. Specifically for sharing content, [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android) should help you along. It explains how to add the SDK to your app, and then how to share content.